# Link to Card in Confluence

Tags: anchor, confluence

I am trying to link to a Card (as in an instance of a Card Macro) in a Confluence page and I cannot get it to work.  The advice I have seen around the web states that I need to make sure that both the Deck of Cards and the Card in question has IDs, and then to use a full web link to access it.  The id for the deck of cards is "MyDeck", the id for the specific card is "MyCard", and the full link in the weblink is:

```
https://www.mydomain.tld/confluence/Page+Title#MyDeck-MyCard
```

(SO rejected the post with the real url, so I anonymized it some.)

When I hover over the link it seems to be correct, but when I click on it, it takes me to the top of the page with the first card open (not the card I have specified in the link).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work with ServiceRocket that maintains this addon macros that you've asked about.

I've managed to achieve your example without any problem. It wasn't clear whether you want to have your link in the same page (where the Deck of Cards are located) or in a different page. In any case, let me answer for both cases.

#### Before You Begin

Make sure you've given IDs to your Deck and all the cards (tabs) in your deck.
[image: Label and Id is filled for each card]

So, my final deck of cards will look like this:
[image]

### Link to a specific tab in the same page

If you have a very long page, and your deck is in the bottom, and you wanted to place your links in the same page, you can use show-card macro. This is documented [here](https://docs.servicerocket.com/composition/macro-reference/show-card) with a tutorial example too.

[image]

### Link to a specific tab but from a different Page

Show card macro will only work in the same page, so here, you will have to manually construct the URL in the other page, but its not that hard. Your approach actually seems correct, but I want you to double check your URL, and ID of the Deck and Card.

First, I copied the view URL of the page that has the deck.
`http://localhost:8090/display/SPACEKEY/composition+example`

Then I added the Deck ID and Card ID as you did:

`http://localhost:8090/display/SPACEKEY/composition+example#Example-Third`

This was working for me. I even added some long lorem ipsum paragraphs to make the deck at the very bottom of the page, and my link would open the page and scroll down to the correct tab at the end of the page.

If it still doesn't work for you, please try and make your IDs more unique (maybe there is some CSS that have the same Ids), otherwise don't hesitate to contact the plugin's support who will be able to help you.